# Replace NaN with another character using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Can you please tell me how to replace `NaN` with another character? There are variables that are assigned some numeric value.
Further in the function, these variables get their values, which I then display in the html `tabl`e. But sometimes some variable returns  `NaN`.

To fix this, I separately created an array with variables that already have some values. Next, I started the loop. If the condition returns `NaN`, then it should be replaced with `"-"`. But it doesn't work.

```js
var a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3, x4;
var elem = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function iFunc() {
  a = 1;
  b = 3;
  c = 2;
  d = NaN;

  x1 = elem('a1').innerHTML = a;
  x2 = elem('b1').innerHTML = b;
  x3 = elem('c1').innerHTML = c;
  x4 = elem('d1').innerHTML = d;

  var arrX = [x1, x2, x3, x4];

  for (var x of arrX) {
    if (x !== x) {
      x = "-"; // the character that was supposed to replace NaN
      console.log(x);
    }
  }
}

iFunc();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="a1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="b1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="c1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="d1"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPD:** with .map()

```js
var a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3, x4;
var elem = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function iFunc() {
  a = 1;
  b = 3;
  c = 2;
  d = NaN;

  x1 = elem('a1').innerHTML = a;
  x2 = elem('b1').innerHTML = b;
  x3 = elem('c1').innerHTML = c;
  x4 = elem('d1').innerHTML = d;

  var arrX = [x1, x2, x3, x4].map(n => n != n ? "-" : n);

  console.log(arrX);
}

iFunc();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="a1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="b1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="c1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="d1"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you've replaced the value of `x` ... not the value in `arrX`

Comment: Hi Yuriy. You can use the `isNaN` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: When you change (or at least try to, see @Bravo's comment) `arrX`, the `innerHTML` of the elements have already been changed, so even if `arrX` was updated as you wanted it to, the changes would not show up.

Comment: @MikePoole `isNaN()` is not very reliable. Its comparison is not the issue here. See the note at the end of my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the value returned by `elem('d1').innerHTML` which won't impact what's in the DOM. What you are trying to do in a simplified way:

```js
var a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3, x4;
var elem = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function iFunc() {
  a = 1;
  b = 3;
  c = 2;
  d = NaN;

  elem("a1").innerHTML = a!=a ? "-" : a;
  elem("b1").innerHTML = b!=b ? "-" : b;
  elem("c1").innerHTML = c!=c ? "-" : c;
  elem("d1").innerHTML = d!=d ? "-" : d;
}

iFunc();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="a1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="b1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="c1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="d1"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To who are suggesting to use `isNaN`, it's not the best way for all use cases, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#confusing_special-case_behavior):

> Alternatively, in the absence of `Number.isNaN`, the expression (`x != x`) is a more reliable way to test whether variable `x` is `NaN` or not, as the result is not subject to the false positives that make `isNaN` unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the value in the array. Currently you are only replacing the value in the variable X.

Here is a solution with a corrected for loop:

```js
var a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3, x4;
var elem = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function iFunc () {
  a = 1;
  b = 3;
  c = 2;
  d = NaN;
  
  var arrX = [x1, x2, x3, x4];
  
  for (var index = 0; index < arrX.length; index++) {
    var x = arrX[index]; // first we extract the value from the array
    arrX[index] = isNaN( x ) ? "-" : x;//then we replace the value in the array
    console.log(arrX[index])
 }
  
  x1 = elem('a1').innerHTML = a;
  x2 = elem('b1').innerHTML = b;
  x3 = elem('c1').innerHTML = c;
  x4 = elem('d1').innerHTML = d;
}

iFunc ();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="a1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="b1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="c1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="d1"></span></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Just learned about it and wanted to share. It seems like `isNaN()`
 is not very reliable. See the note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

a good approach would be to have all values in a array. then you can use a loop to replace the NaN values. Afterwards you can handle the new mapped array like you want.

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 2, NaN].map(n => n != n ? "-" : n)
console.log(arr)
```

**old answer**
You can check with isNaN() or  n != n function and if is true the you can print `"-"`. In your case i would wrap this check in a function. Like this:

```js
function checkNumber(n) {
  return  n != n ? "-" : n;
}
```

```js
var a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3, x4;
var elem = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function iFunc () {
  a = 1;
  b = 3;
  c = 2;
  d = NaN;
  
  x1 = elem('a1').innerHTML = checkNumber(a);
  x2 = elem('b1').innerHTML = checkNumber(b);
  x3 = elem('c1').innerHTML = checkNumber(c);
  x4 = elem('d1').innerHTML = checkNumber(d);
  
  var arrX = [x1, x2, x3, x4];
  
  for (var x of arrX) {
    x = checkNumber(x);
    console.log(x);    
 }
}


iFunc ();

function checkNumber(n) {
  return n != n ? "-" : n;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="a1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="b1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="c1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="d1"></span></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Just learned about it and wanted to share. It seems like `isNaN()` is not very reliable. See the note at the end of my answer.

Comment: @yousoumar thank you for the information and hint! i will replace it in my answer.

Comment: With .map() it doesn't work for me. The previous isNaN solution works, but since the (x !== x) solution is more robust, I'd rather refrain from using isNaN.

In any case, I thank you for your time and help in solving my problem!

Comment: @YuriySab You welcome! I updated my answer again and replace isNaN  function with `n != n`. Best

Comment: I saw an update to your code, thanks! But unfortunately, it still displays NaN in the table, but "-" in console.log.

Comment: @YuriySab I dont know your code and how you implemented. But in my example above workds fine. I could that you forgot to use the new function for your table. `x1 = elem('a1').innerHTML = checkNumber(a);`. And that the new function what you need in your code: `
function checkNumber(n) {
  return n != n ? "-" : n;
}`

Comment: Updated my question and added your code without the checkNumber() function and without the "for (var x of arrX)..." loop. Did you mean it?!

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use `||` symbol to handle `NaN` in Javascript.

```js
var a, b, c, d, x1, x2, x3, x4;
var elem = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function iFunc() {
  a = 1;
  b = 3;
  c = 2;
  d = NaN;

  elem("a1").innerHTML = (a ||  "-"); //using || symbol to handle NaN
  elem("b1").innerHTML = (b ||  "-");
  elem("c1").innerHTML = (c ||  "-");
  elem("d1").innerHTML = (d ||  "-");
}

iFunc();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="a1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="b1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="c1"></span></td>
    <td><span id="d1"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will replace even `0` with `-` while he wants only for `NaN` to be replaced, as you can see on this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/yousoumar/pen/bGvdomZ).